# How to stop developers from opening my website in a WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

An **unauthorized person** has created an android app on our name, logo and showing our website content as is. It has fully functional browser experience in an app. This person is using advertisement to make money using our content.

Our Website: http://www.chittorgarh.com

Fake App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=davidjack.chittorgarh

What we did in last 2 days:

1. Complaint to Google. No response so far.
2. Sent emails to fake app publisher. No response so far.
3. Created our own official app using exact same way and made it live. We will start pushing it through our website soon. It’s not what we want but do not see any other option. 
   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ipo.chittorgarh

Question: **How do disable all the traffic from the Fake App?**

Tried User-Agent but no luck as it’s exactly same as someone opens the app in chrome on android.

Comment: What you can do is report this app for DMCA violations and wait.

Comment: One of the main reasons to NOT build a full-featured, web-only app....

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a web browser within an app, so there isn’t any way around this, if it’s publicly accessible via the web then it’s available to anyone to access or implement within a web view.

All you can do really is create your own app, and add a message regarding the fake app on the homepage of your website.

Comment: Hi Junaid, Thank you for your quick response. Yes we did make our own app, a temporary solution until we launch the actual app. But the fake app looks 100% alike with same logo etc. What I need is some way through which I can show an alert on the fake app and at the same time do not show that message on my own app & traffic  from Chrome browser.

Comment: Hi Mukesh, unfortunately there is no way of targeting the specific app in WebView. Since you have a responsive site, make the message only appear when in mobile mode. Add the message in a general way at the top of the page about the fake app and add a link to your official app in the Play Store, hopefully with time the fake app will get removed. If you have clients emails, email them alerting them about this also